# How to sort based on dependencies?

Tags: python, sorting, dependencies

I have an class that has a list of "dependencies" pointing to other classes of the same base type.

```
class Foo(Base):
    dependencies = []

class Bar(Base):
    dependencies = [Foo]

class Baz(Base):
    dependencies = [Bar]
```

I'd like to sort the instances these classes generate based on their dependencies.  In my example I'd expect instances of Foo to come first, then Bar, then Baz.

What's the best way to sort this?

Comment: Are you asking about a Topological sort in Python?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: Might want to look for "sorting a directed graph", because that's essentially what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's called a topological sort.

```
def sort_deps(objs):
    queue = [objs with no dependencies]
    while queue:
        obj = queue.pop()
        yield obj
        for obj in objs:
            if dependencies are now satisfied:
                queue.append(obj)
    if not all dependencies are satisfied:
        error
    return result
```

Comment: Although your right about the solution needed, this isn't really a complete/usable example.

Comment: @sleepycal: This website is for answering questions, not for providing complete solutions to your problems.

Comment: That's a poor argument, you've posted a code snippet that doesn't work. It's nothing but laziness.

Comment: @sleepycal: I used something called [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).  Pseudocode is not actually supposed to work, it merely illustrates how an algorithm works at a high level.  If you are having problems understanding this answer or filling out the details, feel free to ask a question and I can help you.  Stack Overflow is not a contract programming website, we are here to share knowledge, not to write your code for you.  If you are unsure about community standards, head over to https://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Then you should make this clear in your post, end of discussion.

Comment: @sleepycal: You can identify pseudocode because it uses English phrases in place of functions, such as "if dependencies are now satisfied".  Because that phrase is English, it's pseudocode, not Python.  You can see what actual Python code looks like here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html  Let me know if you have any additional problems understanding things.

Comment: @sleepycal: If you're going to be rude by pretending to not understand something, then you're going to blend in with the people on this site with legitimate questions to ask.  You may wish to review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice (In particular, take a look at the first bullet point under item #3, and the first example in the parenthetical at the end of that bullet point.)

Comment: 2/10 I'm not biting, you'll have to find someone else to troll. Like I said before, your excuse is weak, end of discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar question just last week - wish I'd know about Stack Overflow then!  I hunted around a bit until I realized that I had a *DAG* (Directed **Acyclic** Graph since my dependencies couldn't be recursive or circular).  Then I found a few references for algorithms to sort them.  I used a depth-first traversal to get to the leaf nodes and add them to sorted list first.

Here's a page that I found useful:

[Directed Acyclic Graphs](http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Graph/DAG/)

Comment: Interesting... but no links to these other resources.  Can you provide some of the links to complete the answer to this question?

Comment: I added a link above.  Being new, it would only let me include one in my post, so here's another that has some good background: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/BFSDFS.aspx

Comment: Thanks, the link you provided in your answer is pretty good.  I just wish these university types could actually insert a real graphic once in a while rather than ansi art.  hehe