# A clean algorithm for sorting a objects according to defined dependencies?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list of classes inheriting from this base:

```
class Plugin(object):
    run_after_plugins = ()
    run_before_plugins = ()
```

...and the following rules:

- Plugins can provide a list of plugins that they must run after.
- Plugins can provide a list of plugins that they must run before.
- The list of plugins may or may not contain all plugins that have been specified in ordering constraints.

Can anyone provide a nice clean algorithm for ordering a list of plugins?  It will need to detect circular dependencies as well....

```
 def order_plugins(plugins):
      pass
```

I've come up with a few versions but nothing particuarlly neat: I'm sure some of you [Art of Computer Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) types will relish the challenge :)

[note: question given in Python but it's clearly not only a Python question: pseudocode in any language would do]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

> The canonical application of
>   topological sorting (topological
>   order) is in scheduling a sequence of
>   jobs or tasks; topological sorting
>   algorithms were first studied in the
>   early 1960s in the context of the PERT
>   technique for scheduling in project
>   management (Jarnagin 1960). The jobs
>   are represented by vertices, and there
>   is an edge from x to y if job x must
>   be completed before job y can be
>   started (for example, when washing
>   clothes, the washing machine must
>   finish before we put the clothes to
>   dry). Then, a topological sort gives
>   an order in which to perform the jobs.

Comment: @Eli: I found this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952302/how-to-sort-based-on-dependencies) which mentioned that kind of sort just now but the example given didn't have two separate types of dependencies to be sorted: can that algo deal with this case too?

Comment: @jkp: it can be converted to that representation. i.e. A says that B must run before it, but C after it. So, with only "after" constraints, we say that A is after B, and C is after A.

Comment: @Eli: haha! yes, I guess when you turn it on it's head like that it applies cleanly.  A before constraint on one plugin is just an after constraint for another :)

Comment: Note: A topological sorting will solve the problem, but it may not be necessary. If his 'input' is a single plugin, for which he wants to resolve a sorted list of dependencies, then he has only one 'root' node and he can do a much simpler depth first search with a little checking to detect cycles. The topological sorting algorithm is only necessary if he has multiple 'input' plugins.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.bitformation.com/art/python_toposort.html) is Python code that does topological sorting.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: Yeah, I found that too.  It was a bit long for what I wanted: my version closely matched the example given in the post I linked in Eli's comments.  I learned a new trick anyways which is the main thing :)

Answer (score 1):

This is called [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Doing this involves several steps:

First build a graph of all choosen plugins as vertices and their dependencies as edges. Run before/after deps boil down to the same type of edges.

Next build a transitiv hull: Look at all plugins and add all missing dependencies. Repeat this until the set does not change any more.

Last step: Choose a vertice without incoming edges and do a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search) (or BFS) search. This algorithms can be enriched with cycle detection.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the `__lt__` and associated methods on Plugin based on whether or not they should be run before or after then it could be possible to find a sane ordering with `sorted()`. Cycles would still be a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give good diagnostics for the case that there are cycles, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component. I think that if you use a version of a Strongly connected component like the one outlined in http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/373/notes/lecture16/lecture16.html you can get it to print out the strongly connected components in topological sort order.